# WildFly datasource connection-properties

Tags: database-connection, wildfly

I'm using WildFly 21.0.1-Final.
My problem is that I want to set a custom connection property for the Oracle driver.  I am not able to do that using jboss-cli nor admin console web interface.
The default property is:
[image]
jboss-cli error:
[image]
Web app error:
[image]

I'm getting the error. It looks like the '$' sign is a problem .... ???
Appreciate any help! Thanks in advance )

Comment: You need to escape it from the cli by doubling it

Answer (score 0):

Finally escaping $ sign with the back slash did the trick.  But I should admit that this approach works only with jboss-cli and not with Web Management Console.

Thanks ehsavoie for giving me the hint.

Comment: And just to make it clear - it's also possible to write connection property right into datasource config in the standalone.xml configuration.<connection-property name="v$session.program">
                        property_value_goes_here
                    </connection-property>